# Disqus Comments in android

Tags: android, wordpress, disqus

**Quick View:**

I have a wordpress website having hundreds of disqus comments against certain post.

**Work:**

I have made android app that shows the posts and it's relevant comments and i am retrieving it through rest api in json form.

**Problem:**

I want to integrate disqus comment system i.e. post and retrieve comment in my app for certain post in same chronological order as in my live wordpress site. But the problem I am facing is that many guys have done the same in webview which I don't want/have to use. Is there any way, android sdk, solution available to counter this?

Comment: since you're already using the rest api, why don't you use the same api to post and retrieve comments?  I'm not aware of an android sdk.

Comment: @iConfused is integrating disqus in android is good practice?